# Extracting specific html tag from website

Tags: swift

I'm currently trying to extract a specific tag from a website in Swift 4. 
To receive the data i am using an NSURLConnection and encode the data with NSString. The string contains the whole website including HTML-Tags. I would like to extract the tag `<p class="results">` with his contenct.

What do you think is the best way? RegEx or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) Library.
You should use CSS selector to search for items with the desired attributes.
Here is relative documentation:
**[Use selector syntax to find elements](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup#use-selector-syntax-to-find-elements)**

```
do {
    let html: String = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p><p class=\"results\">";
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
    let elements = try doc.select("p[class=results]") /// Here is your elements
} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) Library. You can check the docs for usage they are pretty straightforward.